# Display the image preview only when the mouse is hovered after 1 sec delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I am showing the image preview when hovering over the image. Now I do keep the interval before displaying the preview image. say I set the delay as 1 sec, and within this if I dragged the mouse out of image, it still displays the preview since it is triggered during the mouse enter . How to fix this?

I need to display a preview only on hover after 1sec delay and not if the mouse is not with in the image?

Comment: use a timer(`setTimeout()`) to delay the display

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xfCwU/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic skeleton using [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) can be

```
var timer;
$('img').hover(function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        //do your stuff here
        $('div').show();

        timer = undefined;
    }, 1000);
}, function () {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = undefined;
    } else {
        //hide the preview
        $('div').hide();
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xfCwU/)

Answer (score 2):

On jQuery 1.9+, you could use `delay/finish`:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RX24k/)

```
$("#preview").hover(function(){
    $("img").delay(1000).show(0); // passing 0 to show() will put animation in queue
}, function(){
    $("img").finish().hide(); // finish() will clear any previous delay(), despite what argues the DOC
});
```

Comment: Sorry I use jQuery < 1.9. I will sure test this and pass a comment. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign the setTimeout to a variable on **mouseover event** like this:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() { doSomething(); }, 1000);
```

And then **clear it on mouseout event** so it doesn't show when you hover out of it:

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```